# QGIS v3 ImportError: No module named builtins

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, importerror

I am trying to automate some tasks in QGIS, and I was initially going to use the model builder but I thought I would try some Python instead, using PyQGIS.

I am using this as a quick start guide as I am relevately new to Python. 
https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/running_qgis_jobs.html

Anyway I got the "ImportError: No module named builtins" when trying to run a batch file. 
Having looked on this forum I seen others have the problem (which was a relief) and I see it is a problem with the new version of QGIS, and the solution seemed to be running a batch file in QGIS 3.0/bin/python-qgis.bat which sets up the paths correctly, however I have run this then tried re-running my batch file, and the error still remains.

[image: python-qgis.bat]

[image: import error]

Not sure if I am just doing something wrong, I am quite new to coding so sorry if it is something obvious.